# Minimum distance travelled in order to reach a known maximum acceleration given a constant jerk value?

Tags: calculus, physics

### Problem

Given the following:

- $A$ = maximum acceleration.
- $J$ = constant [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)) (change in acceleration with respect to time).
- Initial velocity and acceleration of 0.

How might one determine the minimum **distance** that must be travelled in order to reach the maximum acceleration?

### Attempt

In the same way that one might solve distance $D$ given a maximum velocity $V$ and constant acceleration $A$ like so:

$D = \frac{V^2}{2A}$

I thought I might be able to apply the same to my problem by swapping out maximum velocity with maximum acceleration, and the constant acceleration for constant jerk, before realising that this seems to give the *velocity* at which the maximum acceleration is reached, and not the *distance*.

$V = \frac{A^2}{2J}$

I'm as yet unsure how to apply what I know so far to determine the *distance* travelled before the maximum acceleration is reached. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### Application Context

I'm currently attempting to improve a linear motion profile for some linear actuators that are present in an art installation that I'm working on in a small team.

Previously, the linear actuator was driven using a constant acceleration selected by us. We could achieve fast movement nicely with high acceleration, and we could achieve slow movement nicely with slow acceleration, however slow movement with a high acceleration resulted in a lot of "chatter" from the motor.

The idea is to use a constant jerk rather than a constant acceleration to achieve smoother behaviour at both low and high speeds. The implementation seems to be almost complete, however I'm struggling to determine the distance at which I should begin decreasing deceleration in order to arrive at the target position with a velocity and acceleration of 0. It occurs to me that this is the same as solving the distance required to reach the maximum acceleration, hence the framing of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\dot{a}=J$, then repeated integration yields

$$ a(t)=Jt+C_1 \xrightarrow{a(0)=0} a(t)=Jt$$
$$ v(t)=\frac{Jt^2}{2}+C_2 \xrightarrow{v(0)=0} v(t)=\frac{Jt^2}{2}$$
$$ x(t)=\frac{Jt^3}{6}+C_3 \xrightarrow{x(0)=0}x(t)=\frac{Jt^3}{6}$$

Solving the last equation for $t$

$$ t=\left(\frac{6x}{J}\right)^{1/3}$$

Substitute in $a(t)$

$$ a=J^{2/3}(6x)^{1/3}$$

Solve for $x$

$$ x(a)=\frac{a^3}{6J^2}$$